# Controlling Do...While() Loop with int variable isn't working

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Edit: Issue was I didn't declare variables outside it

My loop cannot resolve an int as a variable.

Can't try other types of variables, this has to be an integer.

```java
        do {
            System.out.println("Would you like to add any snacks? ");
            System.out.println("1: ($5) Large Popcorn");
            System.out.println("2: ($0) Nothing Else");
            int snackChoice = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("How many of option " + snackChoice + " would you like? ");
            System.out.println("1: One");
            System.out.println("2: Two");
            System.out.println("3: Three");
            System.out.println("4: Four");
            System.out.println("5: Five");
            int snackAmount = input.nextInt();

            switch (snackChoice) { 
            case 1: 
                cost = cost + 5 * snackAmount;
                System.out.println("Your total before tax will be: $" + cost + (5 * snackAmount)); 
            break;

            default: 
                System.out.println("Not a valid option."); 
            break;

            }
        }
        while(snackChoice != 9);
```

Rest of it: https://pastebin.com/Y6Xd24D0

It works. Actual result: It doesn't.

Errors: `snackChoice cannot be resolved to a variable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `do...while` loop is a code block, which means that variables defined in it cannot be seen outside the block. The `while` part is outside the block, so it cannot see `snackChoice`.

Just define `int snackChoice` **before** the `do...while`, **not in it**:

```
int snackChoice;
do {
    System.out.println("Would you like to add any snacks? ");
    System.out.println("1: ($5) Large Popcorn");
    System.out.println("2: ($0) Nothing Else");
    snackChoice = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("How many of option " + snackChoice + " would you like? ");
    System.out.println("1: One");
    System.out.println("2: Two");
    System.out.println("3: Three");
    System.out.println("4: Four");
    System.out.println("5: Five");
    int snackAmount = input.nextInt();

    switch (snackChoice) { 
    case 1: 
        cost = cost + 5 * snackAmount;
        System.out.println("Your total before tax will be: $" + cost + (5 * snackAmount)); 
    break;

    default: 
        System.out.println("Not a valid option."); 
    break;

    }
}
while(snackChoice != 9);
```

Comment: I have snackChoice 9 to exit the loop, is there another way I can exit the loop with a choice? I need the user to be able to choose as many snacks and quantities as they want.

Comment: That's fine. Just define the variable itself before the `do {` statement - so it'll exist ouside the `do..while` block

Comment: @BellaStallman There, I've added the modified code to my answer.

Comment: Alright thank you. When running, and I try option 9 now, it asks me how many I'd like. No matter which option I choose (1, 5, 12) it gives me invalid option and asks again. How can I exit this properly now?